# How to put non Duplicate values in SQLite & Access?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

My Create table Query is:--

```
     String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST "+ TABLE_FORWARDMSG +"("+KEY_ID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+KEY_MSG_BODY+ " TEXT UNIQUE,"+KEY_MSG_ADDRESS+" TEXT UNIQUE,"+KEY_MSG_DATE+" TEXT UNIQUE" +")";
```

and I am access values From This Code:---

```
String selectQuery="SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_FORWARDMSG;
     SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
 Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
  if( cursor.moveToFirst()){

        for(int i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++){
            map.put("msgBody", cursor.getString(1));
            map.put("msgAddress", cursor.getString(2));
            map.put("msgDate", cursor.getString(3));
            user.add(map);
            cursor.moveToNext();

        }

       }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
```

Now My Problem is that:----

If I remove **UNIQUE** from the **CREATE TABLE** Then I get all duplicate values means if I insert same value it create new row, and if I am using **UNIQUE in CREATE TABLE**, then every time **cur.getCount()** value is **1**. I am new in SQLite. Please tell me whats the problem.

Comment: Check this answer please, hope it will help

http://stackoverflow.com/a/1105157/1838457

Comment: you need to start by creating a new map object at each iteration, else you are simply modifying the same object all over again. Also, if you have a unique constraint and try to insert the same row several time, of course you only get one in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like Ok. Maybe you shouldn't make KEY_MSG_DATE like UNIQUE. Try to get more info about what you want to do.

Comment: thenks for ur answer in my case KEY_MSG_ADDRESS was unique already

Answer (score 0):

What you have implemented is that in every entry in every column has to be unique within the column but I assume what you want is that the row containing the columns msgBody, msgAddress and msgDate has to be unique within the table.

You can achieve that by placing all columns together in the UNIQUE clause:

```
UNIQUE(msgBody, msgAddress, msgDate) ON CONFLICT REPLACE
```